# Trouble with a Point Free Representation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, pointfree

Trying understand an error message I got from a line of Haskell I wrote. I changed

```
f x = map digitToInt $ show x
```

to

```
f = \x -> map digitToInt (show x)
  = (map digitToInt).(\x -> show x)
  = (map digitToInt).show
```

and got the following error message on compilation.

```
No instance for (Show a0) arising from a use of ‘show’
The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
Relevant bindings include
  toDigits :: a0 -> [Int] (bound at lab2.hs:14:1)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Show Data.Char.GeneralCategory -- Defined in ‘Data.Char’
  instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
  instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
  ...plus 23 others
In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘show’
In the expression: (map digitToInt) . show
In an equation for ‘toDigits’: toDigits = (map digitToInt) . show
```

Wondering what the compiler is slapping me on the wrist for. `show` is of type `Show a => a -> String (=[Char])` and `(map digitToInt) :: [Char] -> [Int]` so composition of these to morphisms should make sense.

Further, when I run it as a line `(map digitToInt).show $ <some #>` or `((map digitToInt).show) <some #>` directly in the GHCi it works exactly as i want it to. So the function itself encodes the correct behavior.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `f x = map digitToInt $ show x`. Are you typing that into `ghci` without a `let`? Have you imported `digitToInt` from `Data.Char`? What error did you get from `f x = map digitToInt $ show x`?

Comment: This is due to the monomorphism restriction. Your definition is not done through a function binding (but with a simple binding `f = ...`), so the MR applies. Try adding a type signature to work around that., e.g. `f :: Show a => a -> [Int]` before the function definition.

Comment: Alternatively, disable the MR for the whole module adding at the top `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}`.

Comment: Indeed the problem. Thanks for the reference. Very happy with the thorough and well written answer there. Cheers!